# Changing the way of showing how are records showed in database

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create web app on tracking orders. I have problem with the way how is showed assigning orders to my users. If I add a lot of users to the database the roll down menu is not very good looking and it takes long time to find out the correct user. Is there any way to change the roll down menu to the searching bar which will find user based on the string input?

Here is my models.py where I created MyUser and Order.

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

 class Objednavka(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=11)
```

## views.py

```
class CreateOrder(generic.edit.CreateView):
form_class = OrderForm
template_name = "url.html"

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        messages.success(request, f'Order has been created successfully')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Django does not offer this kind of selectors, but it is not so hard to implement one adding external apps.

Check out this one (the one I personally use): https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/

[image: Example of an autocomplete field.]

Comment: I am quite new to the django framework. Is there any guide how to implement it to the existing project? I am not able to do that only with this documentation